# Invoke executable with parameters and catch error output

Tags: powershell

I need to run an executable that requires some parameters in that form

```
c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter -d .....
```

The executable reports something to standard output what should be ignored. The error output lines should be stored in an array of lines for further processing in PowerShell.

I tried

```
$err = & "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter"
Invoke-Command "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter" -ErrorVariable errorOutput
```

The former doesn't catch stderr.
The latter failed because the string contains more than the executable name. `-p` is not part of the executable name. If I omit the double quotes, Invoke-Command interprets the `-p` as abbreviation for "PipelineVariable".

How should I run the executable while getting stderr?

**Edit:**
Inspired by the answer of [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) I tried this

```
$err = $( $output= & "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter" ) 2>&1
```

Unfortunately the result in $err is:

```
Tool.exe : ==> Error: Product Bar\1.01.01 has not been found!
At line:1 char:17
+ ...  = ( $out = & "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter" ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (==> Error: Prod...been found!:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Obviously that's not the stderr output of Tool.exe but also some PowerShell annotation.

**Edit2:**
The variable `$err` is still unusable if the `&` is omitted:

```
$err = $( $output= "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter" ) 2>&1
Tool.exe : ==> Error: Product Bar\1.01.01 has not been found!
At line:1 char:17
+ ...  = ( $out = "c:\Program Files\Tools\Tool -p Parameter" ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (==> Error: Prod...been found!:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below with your exe

I tested it with one of mine which takes 3 arguments and it works as expected

```
$proc = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]@{
    'FileName'               = "C:\Users\Vincen\Desktop\test.exe"
    'Arguments'              = 's d qa'
    'CreateNoWindow'         = $true
    'UseShellExecute'        = $false
    'RedirectStandardOutput' = $true   # to get stdout to $proc.StandardOutput
    'RedirectStandardError'  = $true   # to get stderr to $proc.StandardError
})
$output = $proc.StandardOutput
$error1 = $proc.StandardError
#$output.ReadToEnd()
$error1.ReadToEnd()
```

**EDIT: Added PS Version**

```
$stdderror= "Error"

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Test.exe" -ArgumentList 's d qa' -RedirectStandardError $stdderror -RedirectStandardOutput $stddop -Wait
Get-Content $stdderror
```

Comment: Good edit, with that in place are you able to capture the standard error now ?

Comment: I've made another edit, changed $error to $error1 as the former is used to contain all the errors from the current session.

Comment: @harper, just curious, is the question still partially/completely unanswered. Do let me know any way I can help.

Comment: I was looking for a more PowerShell style solution instead of invoking a .NET CLR class function. But js2010's approach left something that doesn't handle the street output properly. Probably a different problem with the return code of the Tool app. -- Your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @harper, just appended answer with PS oriented style, I also tested it be creating an exe that writes to error stream and invoked it from powershell with the args

Answer (score 0):

$err has the error messages.  Just `( )` wouldn't work.  Both variables would get both outputs.  Edited for your example.

```
$env:path += ';c:\Program Files\Tools'
$err = $( $output = Tool -p Parameter ) 2>&1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give the plain error output to the variable `$err`. I extended the question with details.

Comment: The powershell in the error message is because you used the call operator "&".

Comment: The PowerShell message is still in the variable `$err` content even if the ampersand is omitted. Example is in the question. It's interesting that the plain output appears only when it's assigned to the variable.

Comment: You're not doing what I suggested.

Comment: Hmm. There is a assignment to a variable inside the parentheses `$out = `. There are parentheses around the inner assignment `$( ... )`. There is a redirection `2>&1`. The result is assigned to `$err`. Can you enlighten me, what did I miss?

Comment: Add c:\program files\tools to the path, then run `tool` by itself with no quotes and no folder in front of it.